# @KafkaListener handling headers added by Spring Cloud

Tags: kafka-consumer-api, spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka

I have implemented a Kafka simple topic consumer via Spring Boot, and I want to use @KafkaListener annotation to get messages. So far so good, I'm happy with Kafka approach I have. 
The issue I have at this point is that the content sent to this topic by a third party and that I'm reading, is produced I think by cloud stream bindings and has headers like these: 
ï¿½contentType   "text/plain"originalContentType   "application/json;charset=UTF-8"

In front of the message. What I'm trying to achieve here is that I want to extract the payload as a string, without all the extra headers that I don't need.

Is there a way to do this keeping the @KafkaListener approach ? How can I handle properly the headers ?

Thanks,

Stefano.

Comment: Something similat to what is described here: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/952

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the point is with the `embeddedHeaders` for the `headerMode`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Elmhurst.SR1/reference/htmlsingle/#_producer_properties. I wonder if you can upgrade to the latest Spring Cloud Stream to rely already on the built-in headers feature in the Apache Kafka. I mean on that Spring Cloud Stream producer side. Or consider to disable embedding headers there. Another option might be to use a `@StreamListener` on your consumer side instead of the `@KafkaListener`.

Comment: Yep, thanks, I was getting something similar and agree fully with you. I can try the StreamListener, although that would be my second option, as my topic is named for the data format to be json and for the content type etc. So really, I can avoid transferring other data and be more inter-operable from a topic content perspective, to avoid other consumers to be forced to use StreamListener as well.